# Title doesn't change when edit to title has been made

Tags: bug, status-review, edits, title, live-refresh

At one point, while watching one of my questions for comments, The "An edit has been made to this post" message showed up. I clicked the message, but I saw no difference between the unedited question and the edited one. So I reloaded the page to find that the title had been changed. I found out that when the "An edit has been made to this post" message gets clicked, only the question's body and tags get updated, but not the title. Could we fix this?