# Clarity for "Linked" posts?

Tags: feature-request, linked-questions

In this question, it says there is a post linked to it, but there isn't any link at all in the comments or the post! I assume the comment with it was deleted? But no, the question was linked from *another* question! Maybe we can add some clarity to distinguish the two?

[image]

You may think that you can just look at the question for links from that question to other questions and look at the linked section for the other way around. The problem I see here is that for *really long questions*, I am unable to find which links that are linked to others, and which are linked to this question.

Comment: Is this about a *specific* page (the title)?

Comment: I guess @This_is_NOT_a_forum was asking about your previous title (Should we remove Linked Posts) if you meant that only the specific question shown in the screenshot had a problem, or if you intended this question to be more general. Now that you changed the question is it more clear that it was just an example and you are asking about the Linked Posts section in general. Note that with your edit you more or less invalidated the existing answer that explains why the linked question was there, it would have been better to ask a new question about clarifying the links.

Comment: That said I think it is a good idea, a proposal could be to prefix the link title with  or  or ⬌ for questions linked from, to, or both from and to the current question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to see if there are posts being referenced in the question or answers you're looking at because you can see that straight away. It's the opposite link direction that's not otherwise discoverable.

Click on the linked post [and you get to a post that starts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/380978/how-do-we-draw-attention-to-our-bug-reports?noredirect=1&lq=1)

> I posted [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/380934)...

so there's a link from there to the [Title doesn't change when edit to title has been made](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/380934/title-doesnt-change-when-edit-to-title-has-been-made) question.

It's pretty useful to know if some other post is referencing the one you're looking at, perhaps it has some relevant information in it.